# Are there any pitfalls to having two different Models from two different assemblies? (EF)

Tags: entity-framework

I have two projects, both of them data access layers, and both using EF. I have another project calling services related to the two different assemblies. Are there any pitfalls on using two different models on two different databases linked to the same database?

I'm asking this because I've been getting this generic "EntitySqlException"

> could not be resolved in the current scope or context. Make sure that all referenced variables are in scope, that required schemas are loaded, and that namespaces are referenced correctly., near escaped identifier.

that does not appear when are run separately but appear when under the same project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just an indication that EF isn't able to find the connection string in your config with that name

Answer (score 1):

You have to put both the connection strings in the app.config/web.config of the project that actually runs.